# Not sure how to declare a variable in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am confused on how to declare a variable into a MSSQL Statement. I keep getting page not showing up.  Here is a partial code from my project.

```
<?php
  include 'users.php';
  require_once("db_connect.php");

 //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User=$user1 ORDER BY id DESC);
 $stmt->execute();  
?>
```

Comment: Oh, the humanity!  You're exposing yourself to SQL Injection here.  Tons upon tons of information out there about it. Here's a good [post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/04/what_2700_s-the-right-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-php-scripts_3f00_.aspx)

Comment: The whole code is written in prepared statement this is partial code so I should not be getting any sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this at the moment, but I noticed there was a quote missing, and I would 
append the variable to the query.

```
<?php
  include 'users.php';
 require_once("db_connect.php");

 //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User=".$user1." ORDER BY id DESC)";
            $stmt->execute();
```

I apologize in adance if this isn't helpful. heh.

Comment: This should be using parameters unless you like sql injection.

Comment: my db_connect.php is written in prepared statements and this is written in prepared statements not sure how this would get sql injections. I use parameters on the codes I insert to the database. Not sure how to write a select statement better than this.